# How do I get IntellijIdea to recognize the syntax in my build.sc file?

Tags: scala, intellij-idea, mill

Here is my `build.sc` file:

```
import mill._
import $ivy.`com.lihaoyi::mill-contrib-playlib:$MILL_VERSION`,  mill.playlib._
object core extends PlayModule {
    //config
    override def scalaVersion= T{"2.12.8"}
    override def playVersion= T{"2.7.3"}
    override def twirlVersion= T{"1.5.0"}

    object test extends PlayTests

    def forkEnv = Map("APPLICATION_SECRET" -> System.getenv("APPLICATION_SECRET"))
}
```

And here is the syntax highlighting in IntellijIdea:
[image]

As the screenshot shows, IntellijIdea does not recognize the `->` and the `$ivy` import. How do I get it to do so?

Comment: The red import is normal. But the `->` should not be red. How do you created the IDEA project, with `mill mill.scalalib.GenIdea/idea`? And what version of mill are you using?

Comment: @TobiasRoeser thanks for this quick response. I am using mill version `0.5.2`. Yes, I used the command `mill mill.scalalib.GenIdea/idea` to create the IDEA project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see, if you look at the top of your editor window, your IntelliJ IDEA warns you about an undefined JDK. Just click on it and tell IDEA which JDK it should use. After that, the `System.getenv` call will be resolved, as it comes from the JDK itself and the red marker should vanish.

The red `import $ivy` is currently *normal*, though.

Comment: This worked. Dumb oversight on my part. I chose the Java 11 SDK, and prefixed `def forkEnv` with `override`, and that took care of those syntax highlighting errors. Thanks!